# How to make Laravel belongsTo relation get data according to condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Using **Laravel 5.2**, I'm trying to use **belongsTo** method to get data from more than one table and it should be according to a condition, such as this in Eloquent Model:

```
public function deals() {
    if($this->section=='offers') {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Deals\SellOffer', 'record_id');
    } else if($this->section=='requests') {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Deals\QuoteRequest', 'record_id');
    } else {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Deals\Partnership', 'record_id');
    }
}
```

Then inside the controller just call the deals method:

```
    $data = Options::with('deals')->get();
```

The Options Table has a column called "section", this should reference to 1 of the 3 tables.

Is that possible to do this, after running the code, it always call the code inside else.

Comment: when you make dd($this->section) what do you get ?

Comment: Did you tried to use [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)?